# Somar linhas do DataGrid com valor fixo em C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

tenho um DataGrid onde cada linha adicionada via clic tem o valor de R$ 2,50
Ex: uma linha soma R$ 2,50, duas linhas Soma 5,00, tres Linhas soma 7,50
porem quando a soma aparece esta sem o zero, 2,5 ,5 , 7,5
alguem poderia me ajudar? fico muito agradecio, tenho o seguinte codigo

```
        double Valor = 2.50; 
        int total = 1 ;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridLabel.Rows)
        {
                lblTotal.Text = total.ToString();
                total = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridLabel.Rows.Count);
                lblValor.Text = "R$ " + Convert.ToString((total * Valor));
        }
```

Comment: você precisa apenas dessa linha: `lblValor.Text = (dataGridLabel.Rows.Count* Valor).ToString("C2");`

Comment: Rovann Linhalis
 muito obrigado, funcionou perfeito tambem, pena que não posso marcar como resposta, não tenho pontos o suficiente

Comment: aqui é um comentário, não dá pra marcar mesmo... dá uma lida no meta que lá tem bastante coisa explicando como perguntar, e como usar os recursos da comunidade.

Answer (score -3):

Nesse caso você pode usar o string.Format
um exemplozinho aqui pra oce

```
double num = 123.456789;
string formattedNum = string.Format("{0:f2}", num); // formata para 2 casas decimais
Console.WriteLine(formattedNum); // imprime "123.46"
```

Comment: não consegui implementar o meu codigo com o teu, ele formata o numero mas dai não soma as linhas.

Comment: Obtigado por ajudar, consegui fazer assim : string formattedNum = string.Format("{0:f2}", Valor * total);
                lblValor.Text = formattedNum;